# "super" or "base" Template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, overriding

If I override a parent block, how do I include the parent inside of the overridden copy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance):

> If you need to get the content of the block from the parent template, the `{{ block.super }}` variable will do the trick.

Comment: +1 looked through a lot of the docs but somehow missed that; thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Don't forget to mark this question as answered. I'm sure @Ignacio wouldn't mind the credit.

Comment: A certain amount of time has to pass before you can accept an answer.

Comment: @chrisdpratt: Thanks for the reminder, although I think I've mostly learned how this site works by now. ;) I couldn't accept it at first and had to come back after 10 minutes.